# Django views not able to show the dictionary object data

Tags: python, django

I have the below queryset

```
   query_data= <QuerySet [{'month': datetime.date(2022, 1, 1), 'count': 9}, {'month': datetime.date(2021, 12, 1), 'count': 9}]>
```

But when I try to do in views

```
  {% for mm in query_data %}
             <span>{{mm['month'] | date: 'F' }}</span>
 {%endfor%}
```

It is not showing the data

but if I did `<span>abcd</span>` it is showing the abcd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template you have to use the [dot-notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) to access dictionary keys:

```
{% for mm in query_data %}
  <span>{{ mm.month | date: 'F' }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: is it possible to add it in span id attribute like <span id="{{mm.month | date: 'F'}}"> </span>

Comment: Yes, you can put Django template codes literally everywhere, just make sure that the resulted string is correct in the given environment.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `mm.month`

```
{% for mm in query_data %}
  <span>{{ mm.month | date: 'F' }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Also there must be space before and after `%` in your templates. There is no space in your `endfor`

Comment: My pleasure @Rajarshi DAs